# Add spaces before capital letter

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sql-server-2014

does anyone know if it's possible to add spaces in a string before every capital letter? I have an SQL query where one of the columns has values saved without space and I need to add spaces in between the concatinated word.

For example, I have `CakeStandsUtensils` and looking to separate into `Cake Stands Utensils`.

Tried googling but not sure if I'm not asking the question correctly, but couldn't find any answers... :( and sincere apologies if this question was asked previously in here...

Using MS SQL Server 2014

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: correct, using MS Access but then compiling an SQL and using ODBC connection to create a table in EXCEL

Comment: So where does SQL Server 2014 come into it? All we need to know is what product the `SELECT` needs to work with, is it running against SQL Server database engine (so needs TSQL) or needs the Access dialect?

Comment: Also, remember when you query an SQL Server linked table inside MS Access you will be running in Access' SQL dialect. However, if you run pass-through queries inside MS Access to a connected SQL Server you will run in SQL Server's dialect (or TSQL). Please advise on your overall process.

Comment: oh... this is a lot of news to me... still learning all of it...
So I'm running SQL via ODBC connection in EXCEL (if that makes sense). In a connection, I have DRIVER=SQL Server. I'm assuming I'm using TSQL, sorry for confusion

Comment: I would assume that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not a query that I'm very proud of but it does the job (assuming you only care about capital letters in English language)

```
SELECT 
LTRIM(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
YourCol COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
,'A',' A')
,'B',' B')
,'C',' C')
,'D',' D')
,'E',' E')
,'F',' F')
,'G',' G')
,'H',' H')
,'I',' I')
,'J',' J')
,'K',' K')
,'L',' L')
,'M',' M')
,'N',' N')
,'O',' O')
,'P',' P')
,'Q',' Q')
,'R',' R')
,'S',' S')
,'T',' T')
,'U',' U')
,'V',' V')
,'W',' W')
,'X',' X')
,'Y',' Y')
,'Z',' Z')
)
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Agree, not the prettiest way but does the job :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that you're opening a table from inside your MS Access accdb file, or are externally linked to a database which is recognized as part of the *CurrentDb* object. If not, it assumes that you know how to connect to your particular external database and/or server.

```
'WARNING! This contains no object testing or error checking!

'Connection to open or linked database
Dim db As Dao.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableName")

'Temporary search and append strings
Dim strField As String
Dim strAppend As String
Dim strUpdate As String

'Begin Record Traversal
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    strField = rs!NoSpacesField
    Debug.Print strField

    'Traverse field characters
    For i = 1 To Len(strField)
        strAppend = Mid(strField, i, 1)

        'Test for capitals and append space. Asc() assumes ascii characters.
        'Use AscW() for Unicode
        If Asc(strAppend) > 64 And Asc(strAppend) < 91 Then
            strAppend = " " & strAppend
        End If
        strUpdate = strUpdate & strAppend
    Next i

    'Trim initial space and update DB field
    strUpdate = LTrim(strUpdate)
    With rs
        .Edit
        !NoSpacesField = strUpdate
        .Update
        Debug.Print !NoSpacesField
    End With
    strUpdate = ""
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
'End Record Traversal

'Cleanup
rs.Close
db.Close
```